# Can't use django Form.clean() method

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to add some extra validation to a form overriding it's clean method but the error doesn't raises, a ValueError exception saying "The view apps.orders.views.view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." raises instead, but if I make an else clause in the if condition to check if the form is valid or not and print form.errors it prints the error created in the clean method. For the record, I'm usin the form along with a formset. Thanks in advance.

Here the form:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ModelForm Class for Orders objects."""
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'executor_signature_date': forms.DateInput(
                format=('%Y-%m-%d'),
                ),
            'customer_signature_date': forms.DateInput(
                format=('%Y-%m-%d'),
                ),
        }
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        check_diagnosis = cleaned_data.get("check_diagnosis")
        repair = cleaned_data.get("repair")
        install = cleaned_data.get("install")
        maintenance = cleaned_data.get("maintenance")

        if (not check_diagnosis) and (not repair) and (not install) and (not maintenance):
            self.add_error(None, "At least one modality option must be checked.")
        else:
            return cleaned_data
```

The check_diagnosis, repair, install and maintenance fields are BooleanField.

Here the view:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=order)
    ItemTimesFormSet = modelformset_factory(ItemTimes, exclude=['order'])
    formset = ItemTimesFormSet(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        order.items.clear()
        form.save()
        for form in formset:
            if form.cleaned_data.get('item'):
                item = form.cleaned_data.get('item')
                times = form.cleaned_data.get('times')
                ItemTimes.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    item=item,
                    times=times
                )

        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any specific error when the form is not valid, just update your view like this to handle errors in the form:

```py
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=order)
    ItemTimesFormSet = modelformset_factory(ItemTimes, exclude=['order'])
    formset = ItemTimesFormSet(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        order.items.clear()
        form.save()
        for form in formset:
            if form.cleaned_data.get('item'):
                item = form.cleaned_data.get('item')
                times = form.cleaned_data.get('times')
                ItemTimes.objects.create(
                    order=order,
                    item=item,
                    times=times
                )

        return redirect(self.success_url)
    else:
        # Form is not valid, handle the error
        print(form.errors)  # Optional: Print the form errors for debugging

        # Provide an appropriate response, such as rendering the form again with the errors
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'formset': formset,
        }
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

and also it is better to add errors to your form like this:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    check_diagnosis = cleaned_data.get("check_diagnosis")
    repair = cleaned_data.get("repair")
    install = cleaned_data.get("install")
    maintenance = cleaned_data.get("maintenance")

    if (not check_diagnosis) and (not repair) and (not install) and (not maintenance):
        raise ValidationError("At least one modality option must be checked.")

    return cleaned_data
```